# Doesn't razor accept space as the first character when concat strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I have the following element in .NET6 Application's razor view:

```
<input type="number" placeholder=@((Model.Child?.Name ?? "DefaultName") + " SomeExtraText")>
```

Expected output when the Name attribute is not null is: **"Name SomeExtraText"**. However I only get **"Name"** as the output.

When I change **" SomeExtraText"** to **"-SomeExtraText"** I get the output as **"Name-SomeExtraText"**.

I also tried using String.Format as follows:

```
<input type="number" placeholder=@(String.Format("{0}{1}",(Model.Child?.Name ?? "DefaultName"), " SomeExtraText"))>
```

but the result is same.

**What is the reason for that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add additional quotes:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="@((Model.Child?.Name ?? "DefaultName") + " SomeExtraText")">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain?

Comment: @EmreUtkuSolak: You are welcome! I'm  doing it according the definition: [HTML placeholder Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_placeholder.asp). _BTW sometimes looking on the generated HTML (like View Page Source in the browser) is helping to understand the problem._

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Isn't string + string = string??? So when I do "a"+"b" the result is "ab" but when I do "a"+" b" the result is "a" but not "a b". Isn't it a bit weird.

Comment: @EmreUtkuSolak: As you known the `cshtml` is processed by the MVC and compiled into HTML, that passed to the client side, as usual. When put your expression without quotes you will have `<input type="number" placeholder=DefaultName SomeExtraText>` after compilation and the `placeholder` will display only `DefaultName` text. If you put  your expression inside quotes the `<input type="number" placeholder="DefaultName SomeExtraText">` will be generated and the `placeholder` will display `DefaultName SomeExtraText` text.

Comment: All clear now. Thanks again.